# A bot to Access data on grid of a windows application (like a human)

Tags: c++

I'm so desperate to use a vpn application. In this app there are some limitations that I've found no solutions for them for example multiple users can connect to the vpn server using one username at the same time. In order to stop that I have to look at the 'connected vpn clients' and see if a username exists more than once and then disconnect him.

Here is a photo of the app page:
[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/3937/kerioq.jpg](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/3937/kerioq.jpg)
Is it possible to develop an application to access this specific grid on this application and read the content and magically use some of those actions (like disconnect menu as you can see)

Comment: The grid I'm talking about is the part with username-operating system-hostname,.....

Comment: The short answer is "No", the long answer is "Yes, but incredibly difficult, and at that will be brittle". The answer to the queston you should be asking (i.e. "How to limit user access to a VPN to one connection per user") is probably available on serverfault.com

Comment: Any lead to how to rich the long answer? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution which reads the GUI will leave connections open for a short amount of time, and be brittle against changes in the GUI, you will be better off asking Kerio support or serverfault if there is any proper, integrated way to achieve what you want.

It can be done, although C++ is probably the wrong choice, python + pywinauto might be a better choice.

Use pywinauto to enumerate the components of the window till you work out how to get to the list. Work through the list, finding duplicates, and disconnecting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Win32 API to get at the controls. You'll need to enumerate the windows to find the one you want, then send the control the messages you want it to respond to. If you're not familiar with using window handles and messaging you'll want to do some reading before you start playing with it.

Some links to start with:

[EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx)